# How to set fastlane language to upload new app to itunesconnect

Tags: app-store-connect, fastlane

When using CI to upload an app using fastlane I get the following error

> Please enter one of available languages: ["Arabic", "Catalan",
>   "Croatian", "Czech", "Brazilian Portuguese", "Danish", "Dutch",
>   "English", "English_Australian", "English_CA", "English_UK",
>   "Finnish", "French", "French_CA", "German", "Greek", "Hebrew",
>   "Hindi", "Hungarian", "Indonesian", "Italian", "Japanese", "Korean",
>   "Malay", "Norwegian", "Polish", "Portuguese", "Romanian", "Russian",
>   "Simplified Chinese", "Slovak", "Spanish", "Spanish_MX", "Swedish",
>   "Ukrainian", "Thai", "Traditional Chinese", "Turkish", "Vietnamese"]

This does not happen if I upload using my own machine and only happens for new apps that are not yet on itunesconnect.

I'm quite inexperienced with fastlane so maybe I'm missing something really easy.

I do have a de-De language folder that fastlane should be used for the language but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by copying the de-De folder into our Fastlane folder. Apparently this was the issue. I'm not sure why it worked on my machine but not on CI like this.